# Сквозное (транзитное) соединение Socket

Tags: c#, сокет

Вопрос.
Есть сервер. К нему подключается Клиент по порту ХХХ. Второй клиент также подключается по этому же порту.
Есть ли возможность создать сквозное соединение на сервере, чтобы через него оба клиента обменивались данными, как если бы один из них коннектился к статическому ip?

Используя .NET Socket Class, ну и вообще как всю эту тягомотину реализуют серверы коммутаторы?

Comment: программное решение будет замедлять скорость. ищите аппаратное решение.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 3):

Разумеется, можно. В чем вообще проблема? Читаем из первого сокета, пишем во второй. В другом потоке читаем из второго сокета и пишем в первый.

---

Роберт, не надо редактировать мой ответ чтобы сказать мне что-нибудь. Надо было выйти из-под аккаунта Натали, зайти под Робертом - и написать нормальный комментарий.

---

Теперь отвечаю на ваш вопрос. Никакого специального транзитного режима сокетов не существует - просто потому что такая задача стоит очень редко. Приоритет потокам можно поднять - а можно и не менять, это зависит от важности задачи и загруженности сервера.

Если же вам нужны готовые решения - посмотрите в сторону прокси-серверов SOCKS 5 и технологии VPN.

Answer (score 1):

Если все же нужен программный подход, я бы, помимо написания простого решения "читай один - пиши в другой и наоборот", обратился бы к протоколу STUN, и уже на его основе искал "велосипеды"